# How to get access to Views from inflated layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have a simple Activity with its main.xml attached. main.xml has a custom layout (customLinearLayout) and a simple TextView. The custom layout also have its own layout-file (linearlayout.xml) with a simple Button. The layout is inflated by the class properly.

The Button in linearlayout.xml shall change the text of the textView lying in main.xml, but I can't get access to that textView. What am I doing wrong? I can't inflate the main.xml either.

Here's the customLinearLayout:

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

LayoutInflater mInflater;
View ContainerView;

Button button1;
TextView tv;

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ContainerView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.linearlayout, this, true);

    button1 = (Button) ContainerView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // trying to get the TextView from main.xml
    tv = (TextView) ContainerView.findViewById(R.id.textview1); // doesn't work

    // these tries doesn't work either
    //tv = (TextView) ContainerView.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textview);  
    //tv = (TextView) this.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textview);
    //tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tv != null)
                tv.setText("works");
            else
                Log.d("CustomLinearLayout", "TextView not found");
        }
    });
}
}
```

the layout-file (linearlayout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="press" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity:

```
public class TestLayoutViewsv2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

The Activity's main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<test.layoutviewsv2.CustomLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `findViewById` is scoped - your custom view is looking inside itself for a text field that doesn't exist.  But that's ok! your views should be their own little world - They shouldn't need to know anything about the world outside itself.  Sadly you'll have to change your design to accomodate this (like with a callback to the activity, perhaps) to make this do what you want to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess my thoughts were wrong. I assumed that the views would join the main.xml after inflating, so that i could go back the hierarchy. I guess I have to read up on using Callbacks then. Are there any other ways for letting a view know that another view had changed? (eg. tell a button to switch back to its initial state, when another view or class finished his job)

Comment: @user1349812 nope, that's pretty much the only way -> your activity manages the states of all its views.  Like I said, the view exists in its own little world - it can tell the mothership that something has happened, and its the mothership's job to make sure all of the relevant other views change according to the information it received

Comment: But wouldn't that mean, that there is only one hierarchy-layer which controls all of the UI? What about the idea of splitting the UI into some ViewGroups, in order to avoid an overloaded Activity? How is that handled? - last question I promise :)

Comment: well if your ViewGroups are customized, they can control the behaviour of their children, so if action on child A should affect child B, then the ViewGroup can manage that, but information flow can really only go up the tree or down the tree, not jump from branch to branch.  as far as avoiding an overloaded activity, try using fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html Even if you're developing for older platforms they've been integrated into them via the support package

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me out. Also I didn't know Fragments may be used in older versions. I will consider that too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the inflate method in a wrong way..there is no point of inflating a layout if you are extending a view. The inflate method is used to init a new view without the need to create a new instance yourself. I am not getting what your are trying to do but you could use the include to reuse some of your layouts. Check this for more info http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: Yes, that was just a simple example of the actual problem I have. I just want to let a view know that another view has changed its state (like telling an activated button to switch back to its initial state, when another view or class finished its job). With inflating I thought I could gain access to views that were put in a layout, so that I could get their state programmatically.